# MySqlException: There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an Index.cshtml page with a table that contains a foreign key from another table. I have added a search feature in my index but when searching, it throws this exception :

> **MySqlException: There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first.**

I have ran the debugger and it looks like it is going in my ActionResult just fine but when it tries to load the view, **it crashes at line 11**. I suspect that it's because the item is a foreign key in my db (*which is represented as another class in the models*) since I have added the search feature in other indexes and it works. I have commented the lines 11 and 12 and the exception is not happening anymore.

I am coming to you because even though I seem to have found the problem, I do not really understand why this exception happens and how to fix it. Any help would be appreciated.

PS : I have used the [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application#add-a-search-box) code from the Microsoft Docs for the search feature.

```
1    @foreach (var item in Model)
2    {
3       <tr>
4            <td>
5                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.nom)
6            </td>
7            <td>
8                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.adresse)
9            </td>
10           <td>
11             //   @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.responsable.prenom)
12             //   @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.responsable.nom)
13           </td>
14           <td>
15                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.telephone)
16           </td>
17        </tr>
18    }
```

### My Controller

```
// GET: cinemas
public ActionResult Index(string searchString)
{
    IndexCinema_ViewModel viewModel = new IndexCinema_ViewModel();

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
    {
        viewModel.Cinemas = db.cinemas.Where(s => s.nom.Contains(searchString)
                || s.responsable.nom.Contains(searchString)
                || s.responsable.prenom.Contains(searchString));
        ViewBag.searchRequest = true;
    }
    else
    {
        viewModel.Cinemas = db.cinemas.Include(c => c.responsable);
        ViewBag.searchRequest = false;
    }

    ModelState.Clear();
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Never send an `IQueryable<T>` or non-materialized `IEnumerable<T>` outside a controller action!**:  Notice how [in the example you linked to on Microsoft's website](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application#add-a-search-box), the code calls `ToList()` **prior** to returning `View(model)`.

You need to materialize your query to a `List<T>` in your Action so that the `DbContext` can be disposed-of safely and not leave dangling connections open:

```
viewModel.Cinemas = await db.cinemas
    .Include(c => c.responsable)
    .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: I have only added `ToList();` to my query, because I am not familiar with async methods and more importantly with MVC since it is my first project. I would love to know more about it. Do you recommend ressources that I could read that would help me on it? Also could you explain why it is a bad practice to send an IEnumerable outside a controller?

Comment: @pensum If the `IEnumerable<T>` represents a lazily-evaluated database query then the query won't be executed until the `IEnumerable<T>` is iterated-over in a `foreach` or `.ToList()` method (for example) - which means the database connection associated with the query will be kept-alive and unable to be used by other parts of your application until after the view is rendered - or if your Controller (or ASP.NET itself) disposes of your `DbContext` prior to the view being rendered then the query cannot be executed at all.

Comment: @pensum The lifetime of a non-evaluated `IQueryable<T>` is bound to the lifetime of its parent `DbContext`, by returning an `IQueryable<T>` (even if it's represented as an `IEnumerable<T>`) from your Controller Action then it may outlive its parent `DbContext`. Languages like Rust have built-in syntax for denoting object lifetimes and I wish C#' had a feature like that because it would really help in situations like these.